# Image Field Issue

Tags: views, 8, media

I seem to be having a weird issue with my site where if I create a new content type, add the standard image field with whatever settings and then create content for it, the image automatically always is created as a link to itself like this: **(public://image-folder/image-name.jpg)**. I have no idea where this is coming from? Even if I try to create a view to display these images and choose Link Image to Nothing, it still links to the above. Even if I try to rewrite the results and select Output this Field as a Custom Link, it doesn't work. It seems to always just link the image to that "public" link. (which just gives an error since it doesn't work).

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening or has anyone ever run into something like this?

Drupal: 8.3.2

Comment: In manage display, check that your format is image, like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgTUu.jpg). If you're already using image, then change your Drupal theme, and see if the same issue still occurs.

Comment: Yeah, it is set to image. I have a custom bootstrap sub theme running. I'll see if changing it does it but don't see how.

Comment: Changing the theme didn't do anything. Anytime I upload an image, it's still forcing it to link to **public://image-folder/image-name.jpg**. Doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Sssweat any other ideas at all as to why this could be happening? Still haven't managed to figure it out.

Comment: Hard to debug without having access to your site. Maybe there is a custom/contrib module that is doing this?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to look further into this and see if any of those is doing it.

Comment: Well, once I updated core, the problem went away so not sure what the real issue was.